# image_view image_saver

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is this error?

```
mike@spinach:~/ros_workspace/phototest$ rosrun image_view image_saver image:=/prosilica/image_raw
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvInitMatHeader, file /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.0-1precise-20120510-1801/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 162
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.0-1precise-20120510-1801/modules/core/src/array.cpp:162: error: (-13)  in function cvInitMatHeader
Aborted (core dumped)
mike@spinach:~/ros_workspace/phototest$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36263/image_view-image_saver/) by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your image is improperly formatted.  "Image step is wrong"

A quick search finds a lot of similar problems: [search](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Image+step+is+wrong)

If you want more information you will need to debug a little more and provide more information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0